# Does the two first order formula interprets to same meaning?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

> 1. [∀x,β →  α(x)]
> 2. [β  →  (∀x,α(x))]

Here α(x) is a first order formula with x as a free variable, and β is a first order formula with no free variable.

Comment: Yes, the two are equivalent.

Comment: @Mauro Yeah, i just landed on this page [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic) ]  which eventually resolved my query. This **∀x,β** is one of the many notation we can use to express quantifier. The ' **,** ' makes it little ambiguous to follow the scope of quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\forall x) [\beta \implies a(x)] \equiv \text{For all $x$, $\beta$ implies $a(x)$}$$
$$\beta \implies (\forall x)[a(x)] \equiv \text{$\beta$ implies that for all $x$, $a(x)$ is true}$$

You didn't specify the domain for $x$, so your statements already have a problem.
Other than that, the two statements are equivalent.